# html for repeater not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, repeater

I am creating a multi-page report for sales reps based on each client for batch report. 
I have placed the entire body in a repeater and item template to repeat the entire page. I don't know if this is possible but I have bound the list of client id and then I want to run the rest of the code for that id using the repeater.
Currently all my code inside the repeater is not visible. I have added do test ids to the list and I have also added a p tag to the top of the body to just check that the code would display something.
I have researched this for the last two days and so far I have not come up with anything that would resolve this issue.

**ASPX CODE**

```
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="header" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="reportName" runat="server">
                            <p class='text-bold-xlg'><asp:Label ID="CampaignNameData" Text="Campaign Name" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                            <p class="text-md"><asp:Label ID="ReportRangeLabel" Text="Report Range: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                               <asp:Label ID="ReportRangeData" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="logo" runat="server">
                    <img src="images/Picture1.jpg" runat="server" enableviewstate="true"/>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="info" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="drPersonal" runat="server">
                            <p class='text-bold-lg'><asp:Label ID="DoctorNameData" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                            <asp:Table ID='drInfoTable' runat="server">
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-bold-md'><asp:Label ID="SpecialtyLabel" Text="Specialty:" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-md'><asp:Label ID="SpecialtyData" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-bold-md'><asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" Text="Address:" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-md'><asp:Label ID="AddressLine1Data" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                                      <asp:Label ID="AddressLine2Data" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                                      <asp:Label ID="AddressLine3Data" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-bold-md'><asp:Label ID="DecileLabel" Text="Decile:" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-md'><asp:Label ID="DecileData" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-bold-md'><asp:Label ID="RepLabel" Text="Rep:" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell><p class='text-md'><asp:Label ID="RepData" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                             </asp:Table>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
                    <img id='main-circle-1' src="images/circle-gray.png" alt=""/>
                        <img id='main-circle' src="images/circle-orange.png" alt=""/>
            <%--                /*create a table*/--%>
                        <asp:Table ID="GraphicCircleData" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text'><asp:Label ID="TotalTouchpointsLabel" Text="Total <br /> Touchpoints" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text'><asp:Label ID="TotalEngagementsLabel" Text="Total <br /> Engagements" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="TouchpointsData" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="EngagementsData" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="timeline" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"  >
                <p class='text-bold-lg' id='timeline-title'><asp:Label ID="LatestActivityLabel" Text="Latest Activity" runat="server" ></asp:Label></p>
                        <img id='timeline-img' src="images/timeline-sq-sm.png" alt=""/>
                        <asp:Table ID="timelineActivity" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tmImg1" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tmImg3" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tmImg5" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-xsm'><asp:Label ID="Timeline1ActivityA" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline1NameB" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline1DateC" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-xsm'><asp:Label ID="Timeline3ActivityA" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline3NameB" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline3DateC" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-xsm'><asp:Label ID="Timeline5ActivityA" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline5NameB" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline5DateC" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-xsm'><asp:Label ID="Timeline2ActivityA" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline2NameB" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline2DateC"  runat="server"></asp:Label><br /></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-xsm'><asp:Label ID="Timeline4ActivityA" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline4NameB" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Timeline4DateC" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tmImg2" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tmImg4" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel class="tableDiv" id="directMail" runat="server">
                <p class='text-bold-lg activity-title'><asp:Label ID='ProgramActivityLabelDm' Text='Program Activity - Direct Mail' runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ></asp:Label></p>
                        <asp:table class="activityTable" id="directMailTable" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="DMSentLabel" Text="Sent" runat="server" ></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>

                        </asp:table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel class="tableDiv" ID="emailDiv" runat="server">
                <p class='text-bold-lg activity-title'><asp:Label ID="ProgramActivityLabelEm" Text="Program Activity - Email" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label></p>
                        <asp:table class="activityTable" id="emailTable" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="EmSentLabel" Text="Sent" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="EmViewed" Text="Viewed" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="EmClicked" Text="Clicked" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel class="tableDiv" ID="ClinCard" runat="server">
                <p class='text-bold-lg activity-title'><asp:Label ID="ProgramActivityLabelCC" Text="Program Activity - ClinCard" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label></p>
                        <asp:table class="activityTable" id="clinCardTable" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="Sent" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="Viewed" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><p class='text-lg'><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="Clicked" runat="server"></asp:Label></p></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</body>
```

**ASPX.CS CODE**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<int> lstHcp = new List<int>();

     lstHcp.Add(1);
     lstHcp.Add(2);

     repeater.DataSource = lstHcp;
     repeater.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `<asp:Form>` tag in your aspx.  ASP.Net will not process without it.

Comment: please update your question with the full text of your ASPX page.  I'll post the changes you need to make in this answer.

Comment: Do you mean like this? <%# Container.DataItem %>